# Visual Studio 2010 Arduino serial communication, c++ code

Tags: visual-c++

I'm using OpenCV in Visual Studio 2010 to detect sleepiness eye of the camera, and I try to send a value to the Arduino to activate buzzer (alarm) and the dc motor will stop after the eye drowsiness is detected (covered) by the camera. I am using the Arduino Uno. I have completed C + + code, but I have trouble sending this data to the Arduino. I am currently using the RS-232 cable for this. I use a type-B USB cable to program my Arduino and RS-232 to try to send data from Visual Studio for Arduino. How can I do it ...

Comment: "I have trouble..." - ***But what trouble!?*** (Apart from using Visual Studio, of course...)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows) written for C++ interface of Arduino, if you want to use it.

If you are just using visual studio as a "logical switch", you just need a serial communication. Check this [link](http://aleksandarkrstikj.com/tracking-a-ball-and-rotating-camera-with-opencv-and-arduino/) also [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S18OH6-GOvw) and [this one](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=69038.0).